# Suitable Php Framework For Shopping Cart Website

Tags: php, joomla, frameworks, web

I'm planning to create a shopping website and want to create it quickly. I'm looking for framework which can provide me good backend(admin section, like joomla provide). Also, I can customize my webpages easily, should not require too much time to understand the framework. I have tried Joomla and when I saw the code it was complex. It would be great if framework provides me the ready made cart section, however, I can modify it according to my requirement.
Please suggest me if any easy framework exists in php or in any other language.

Comment: You have many free shopping cart scripts - i think that Opencart is relatively simple. Try with it...

Comment: Thanks nevermind... I found some of templates which help me to design the website easily. I wanted the Admin section and some of the pages... rest I can design myself.

Answer (score 1):

You want the holy grail of online-shop-systems? Easy to build jet very powerfull?

Sorry mate, but that does not exist. You can either go the simple way. Have an easy to set up system that can't do a lot or you have a powerfull system with a lot of possibilitys that's complex.

Beside that SO is not ment to give opionos but to solve programming-problems and errors. Therefor your question doesn't fit here. Esp. if you show no effort about what you have looked up yourself this far.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question would be [Magento](http://magento.com/). It has all the features which are required by a shopping cart.